# Jquery moving objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm learning to use Javascript and jquery right now and have a rather stupid beginner question. The point of my excersise is to create four objects that move at the same time but the first one should change size onclick and the third one should change color on mouseenter this is what I have so far and can't seem to move on from this point. 
I would really appreciate help on this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      left: '250px'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Animate</button>

<br><br><br>
<div class="first">
  <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;"></div>
  <br><br><br>
  <div class="second">
    <div style="background:#d80000;height:100px;width:100px;"></div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="third">
      <div style="background:#038ef0;height:100px;width:100px;"></div>
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="fourth">
        <div style="background:#ffc50d;height:100px;width:100px;"></div>
```

Comment: Your HTML seems incomplete. Have you intensionally nested the `div` elements? The reason the animation doesn't work is because you need to make the divs `position: absolute` for the `left` style to have an effect

Comment: first close the `<div>` tags for `<div class=first></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must position your div so you can use the `left` property or use `marginLeft` instead of `left` , and you didn't close properly your `html` `div` tags,

Try out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwxqxsLr/1)

**HTML**

```
<button>Animate</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="first">
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;">
</div></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="second">
<div style="background:#d80000;height:100px;width:100px;">
</div></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="third">
<div style="background:#038ef0;height:100px;width:100px;">
</div></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="fourth">
<div style="background:#ffc50d;height:100px;width:100px;">
</div></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: 250}, 1000);
    });
    // change border radius to make it a circle
    $("div.first").click(function(){
        $("div.first div").animate({borderRadius:"50%"});
    });
    // on mouse ove change background color and return at mouse out
    // but you can do this css hover simpler
    $("div.third").mouseover(function(){
        $("div.third div").css("background-color","black");
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $("div.third div").css("background-color","#038ef0");
       });
});
```

**CSS**

```
div{position:relative}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You've helped me figure it out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".first").animate({
      left: '250px'
    });


  });

  $(".third").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate().css({
      backgroundColor: '#000000'
    });
  })


  $(".fourth").mouseout(function() {

    $(this).animate({
      width: 300
    })
  });


});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>Animate</button>

<div class="first" style="background:#98bf21;"></div>

<div class="second" style="background:#d80000;"></div>

<div class="third" style="background:#038ef0;"></div>

<div class="fourth" style="background:#ffc50d;"></div>
```